# Filtered GeoJSON data don't return bindPopup

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have problem with my filtering data bindpopup

Whereas my code looks like this:

```
     //If On-Hold is clicked.
     document.getElementById("On-hold").addEventListener('click', 
   function(event) {
    theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Do_not_design" ';    
    console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'orange',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU")&& 
  (feature.properties.Status == "Do_not_design" );
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
 });
```

Then I don't have Bindpopup window shown with my GeoJSON.property.Owner

Instead of it, the console says:

> leaflet.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at e._updateContent (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e.update (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
>       at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
>       at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
>       at e.openPopup (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e.openPopup (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e._openPopup (leaflet.js:7)

Unless I change the `layer.bindPopup` into `(feature.properties.Status)` then I have this bindpopup window with status shown:

[image]

Is it related with this maybe?

```
  function(event) {
    theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Do_not_design" ';    
    console.log(theExpression);
```

How to make it more versatile for different geoJSON property features?

Comment: Please provide an example that showcases the problem. You can fork my jsFiddle boilerplate here: https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/jsoghrz4/

Comment: Thank you Pal! Hovewer maybe next time, it looks like I found some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this problem can be solved by the following way:

Instead of rely on `.binTooltip` ,which i likely more tailored for `label` properties is better to set the `onEachFeature` properties (popupContent) instead. In this event we must remember to write `layer.bindPopup(popupContent);` underneath the `PopupContent`.

So the final code looks as per below:

```
    mdu = L.geoJson(data, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        //color: "#000",
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillOpacity: 0.8

        }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
        }
        }).addTo(map);

                    // GeoJson layer filteration

                    var myData =  L.layerGroup([]);
                        myData.addLayer(mdu);
                        myData.addTo(map); 

                    document.getElementById("radioOne").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Issued" ';
                    console.log(theExpression); 

                        myData.clearLayers();
                        map.removeLayer(myData);

                    mdu = L.geoJson(data, {

                            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

                                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                    color:'red',
                                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
                                    fillOpacity: 1,
                                    radius: 8
                                })
                            },  
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { //set OnEachFeature with layer.bidnPopup underneath
                                layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
                                var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                                    feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                                    feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                                    feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                                    '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                                    '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';           
                                    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                                        popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                            }
                            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                            },
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                 return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU") && (feature.properties.Status == "Issued" );
                            },

                        });

                        myData.addLayer(mdu);
                        myData.addTo(map);
                    });

                    document.getElementById("radioTwo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    theExpression = 'feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ';
                    console.log(theExpression); 

                        myData.clearLayers();
                        map.removeLayer(myData);
```

where the only difference between the upper one is the onEaachFeature function set.